# New Ubuntu desktop install

Tags: system-requirements

I have a Toshiba Satellite laptop running AMD Turion 64 X2 TL-56 processor (1.79 GHz) with 2 (1.87) GB of RAM. It's an older laptop (I bought it sometime around 2007 or 8 and it's currently running on Windows XP Professional SP3. I was hoping to install Ubuntu as XP support ended quite some time ago. Will I have any issues trying to run Ubuntu on this platform?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Comment: quick answer no. But the RAM is a bit low, look into xubuntu/lubuntu if Ubuntu feels slow. Test it with a live-usb. :)

Comment: Using a minimalist platform sounds appealing to me, even if I had a more powerful computer. Which would you recommend, xubuntu or lubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

If you do, it will almost certainly be around the graphics chipset. Since you didn't provide the model name or number for the Toshiba, it's not possible for me to determine which video chipset you have. I would recommend booting the LiveCD, and if that works, and you get to the installer, you have reasonable assurance that you can perform an installation without issue.